# Intent to install APK file - Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, android-install-apk, android-7.0-nougat

I searched extensively and did not find the problem. When you try to install an `APK file` using an `Intent` in `Android Nougat`, it simply does not install and displays the following warning: "There was a problem parsing the package".

It works perfectly to open `PDF` files, for example, with settings to open this type of file (.`PDF`). However to install .`apk` files does not work.

`LogCat` does not show any errors and I can not reach any solution.

What could be wrong?

The following code:

*Manifest*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="br.com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
    </provider>
```

xml/filepaths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
```

Activity:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "app-debug.apk");
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);

            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/app-debug.apk");

            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Please, what could be wrong with this code? Can someone help me?

Comment: `searched extensively and did not find the problem.` Then try better as this problem has been reported here just a few weeks ago.

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: I am facing error for the path for this. Can you please do check this again for the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the intent for N (and higher) and remove the type designation.  Once I did that the install worked as expected.

So for N:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "app-debug.apk");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);
intent.setData(uri)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```